# Why can't I use localhost to open a file I moved, even though the permissions are the same and I changed DocumentRoot in Apache configuration

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, php

I am learning to use Apache on macOS Monterey. I have a simple test file `test.php`:

```
<?php
echo "Test";
```

I put this file in my home directory (`/Users/my_username`) and update my Apache configuration file (`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`) as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/my_username "                                                                                                                                          
<Directory "/Users/my_username">
... some options
</Directory>
```

Once I have restarted Apache (`sudo apachectl restart`), I can then open `http://localhost/test.php` in my browser, and I get the correct output.

The problem comes when I instead have the file `test.php` in `/Users/my_username/Documents` (or another lower subdirectory). I update the Apache configuration file accordingly, i.e.

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/my_username/Documents"                                                                                                                                          
<Directory "/Users/my_username/Documents">
... some options
</Directory>
```

and again restart Apache. However, now `http://localhost/test.php` gives me this error:

```
Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Failed opening required '/Users/my_username/Documents/test.php' (include_path='.:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.3/share/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Searching for answers online, I thought this issue might be caused by file permissions. But the file permissions in each case are the same:

```
ls -l /Users/my_username/test.php /Users/my_username/Documents/test.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_username  staff  508 Mar  4 12:46 /Users/my_username/Documents/test.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_username  staff  508 Mar  4 13:03 /Users/my_username/test.php

ls -ld /Users/my_username/ /Users/my_username/Documents/    
drwxr-xr-x+ 52 my_username  staff  1664 Mar  4 13:17 /Users/my_username/
drwxr-xr-x+ 12 my_username  staff   384 Mar  4 13:04 /Users/my_username/Documents/
```

Why is the response different even though the permissions are identical?

Comment: @Peregrino69 they are listed in the question.

Comment: Right. Sorry, the way you formatted that is a bit hard to read. I can't get output like that giving those commands.